# Power of simple object cannot be a proper subobject of itself

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I am trying to prove that in every abelian category and for every simple object $A$, for distinct natural numbers $m\neq n$ we have $A^m \ncong A^n$. I am not completely sure whether this is true for all abelian categories; or whether this might even hold for more general objects $A$ (for instance, if it holds for simple $A$, it should also hold for non-zero, semisimple $A$ composed of finitely many direct summands). But let's just assume that $A$ is simple, if this helps. And if assumptions have to be introduced on the category, feel free to do so.

The best instrument available seems to be the fact that $A^n \hookrightarrow A^m$ is a proper subobject for $n <m$ (in many different ways). It therefore suffices to show that $A^n$ cannot be a proper subobject of itself. If it is, we have a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to A^n \overset{f}{\to} A^n \to B \to 0$$
for some $B \cong A^n / f(A^n) \neq 0$. This might not bring us much further... But maybe there is a way to use that $A$ is simple, somewhere?

If we had, for instance, a faithful, exact functor to the category of finite dimensional vector spaces, we could apply it to the exact sequence to get a contradiction (exact implies that the sequence stays exact; faithful implies that $B$ is not sent to $0$). But I don't expect every abelian category to have such a functor.

**Remark:** maybe one could just use that $\mathrm{End}(A)$ is a division ring, $\mathrm{Hom}(A^n,A^m) \cong  \mathrm{End}(A)^{m \times n}$, and non-square matrices cannot be invertible, hence $A^m \ncong A^n$. But this really sounds a bit sloppy, and I am convinced that there must be a more elegant argument.

Comment: In your short exact sequence, $B$ is a quotient of $A^n$, not a subobject. So what do you mean by $A^n/B$ on the next line?

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake, I'll correct it

Comment: Nonzero and semisimple is not enough--you need some kind of finiteness condition (consider a direct sum of infinitely many copies of a simple object).

Comment: Yes, I was assuming direct sums to be finite, if not otherwise specified (and hence semisimple objects to be finite direct sums of simple objects, if not otherwise specified), but I realise that this is not standard and that I should have specified it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $i:A^n\to A^n$ were monic but not epic.  Then $i,i^2,i^3,\dots$ would be an infinite strictly descending sequence of subobjects of $A^n$.  But $A$ is simple, and in particular Artinian, so $A^n$ is also Artinian, so this is impossible.  (More generally, this argument shows an Artinian object cannot be a proper subobject of itself, and a Noetherian object cannot be a proper quotient of itself.)

Separately, let me remark that a much more general statement is true: the Jordan-Hölder theorem is true in any abelian category.  That is, if an object has a composition series (a finite sequence of subobjects where the successive quotients are all simple), then any two composition series have the same length and the same simple quotients up to a permutation.  The proof is essentially the same as for modules.

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of argument that I was looking for. Except for the fact that one should still prove that a finite power of an Artinian object is Artinian. And doesn't one need to use that $A^n$ is not a proper subobject of itself in the proof, somehow? This might get circular... But the reference to Jordan-Hölder is very useful, thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, I have collected quite a number of books on category theory and homological algebra, but none of them mentions the Jordan-Hölder theorem, or even the term "composition series". Only Kashiwara-Schapira has it as an exercise. Do you happen to have a reference for the proof in the general setting of abelian categories? Even if you say that it's the same as for modules, it would just be nice to be able to read it without having to mentally change words and verify why things hold in general all the time :)

Comment: If $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact and $A$ and $C$ are Artinian, then $B$ is Artinian.  The proof in a general abelian category is essentially the same as for modules--given a descending chain of subobjects of $B$, their intersections with $A$ and images in $C$ are descending chains, and when the two chains stabilize so must the original chain.  (This argument also proves a weak form of Jordan-Hölder, namely that any two composition series have the same length, by proving by induction that every strict chain of submodules has length at most the length of a composition series.)

Comment: I don't know of a reference for Jordan-Hölder in abelian categories off the top of my head, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now this is clear. Since we are at it, may I just ask: is it true that *any* subobject $B$ of a semisimple object $A \cong \bigoplus_i A_i^{n_i}$ is semisimple, and in particular that $B$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_i A_i^{m_i}$ for some $m_i \le n_i$ (where the $A_i$ are simple)? And that $A/B \cong \bigoplus_i A_i^{n_i-m_i}$?

Comment: I guess that, in other words, I am asking whether it's always true that $A$ is semisimple if and only if every subobject is a direct summand if and only if every subobject is semisimple

Comment: Let me define "semisimple" to mean every subobject is a direct summand and "finite length" to mean "having a composition series", or equivalently, "both Noetherian and Artinian".  Then every subobject of a semisimple object is semisimple, and every subobject of a finite length object has finite length.  Moreover, a semisimple object of finite length is a finite direct sum of simple objects (and hence so is any subobject, and then the relation $m_i\leq n_i$ follows from Jordan-Hölder).

Comment: It is not true, though, that every semisimple object has finite length (consider an infinite direct sum of simple modules).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And conversely, every (finite?) direct sum of simple objects is semisimple, according to your definition, right?

Comment: That's correct, for finite direct sums.  It's not true for infinite direct sums in an arbitrary abelian category (though it is true for modules).

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks a lot again for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

How about $\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand\End{\operatorname{End}}\Hom(A,A^m)\cong \End(A)^m$ and $\Hom(A,A^n)\cong \End(A)^n$, so as long as $\End(A)$ has [invariant basis number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) (IBN), then the claim holds. However, $\End(A)$ having IBN is essentially the same as non-square matrices over $\End(A)$ not being invertible, so this is essentially the same argument as your remark. (Note that in particular, if $A$ is simple, it is a division ring and division rings have IBN).

That said, I'm skeptical that a proof that doesn't somehow rely on division rings having invariant basis number exists, since the proof above goes backwards.

That is, if $\End(A)$ doesn't have IBN, then $\End(A)^n\cong \End(A)^m$ for some $n\ne m$, and matrices $B\in M^{n\times m}(\End(A))$ and $C\in M^{m\times n}(\End(A))$ such that $BC=I$ and $CB=I$. Then $B$ and $C$ also induce inverse isomorphisms between $A^n$ and $A^m$.

Comment: I thought about this. But then one should show that the $\mathrm{End}(A)$ action is preserved under isomorphism. Let us call the isomorphism $f:A^n \to A^m$. We have a bijection $\mathrm{End}(A^n) \to \mathrm{End}(A^m), \phi \mapsto f\circ \phi \circ f^{-1} $, and we want to show that it is an isomorphism of $\mathrm{End}(A)$-vector spaces. It is not hard, but to do this we are again using matrix multiplication, I think...

Comment: But your last remark is interesting. Maybe I should just make the matrix proof a bit more precise.